# Flutter Location Tracking Issues

Tags: flutter, dart, geolocation, location

I am trying to use live GPS tracking on my app to track user movements but the whole thing is so inconsistent. I am using two of the recommended libraries to achieve this. Here are the two libraries I am using:

- Location: https://pub.dev/packages/location
- Geolocator: https://pub.dev/packages/geolocator

Here is the issue. Both libraries do return coordinates but whenever I am dead still, the GPS coordinates keep jumping around. I literally place my phone on the table and I will see as these two libraries give me different coordinates every second even though my phone is dead still. The coordinates are often within a 10 meter radius I would say but its absolutely throwing off my core app function because I need accuracy or consistency at least. I am most probably missing something, if so could someone please assist. Here is my code using both the libaries:

Location libary:

```
var location = new Location();

        location.onLocationChanged().listen((LocationData currentLocation) {
          print("Coord: ${currentLocation.latitude} ${currentLocation.longitude}");
          _approachingGate
              .getApproachingGate(
                  Position(
                      latitude: currentLocation.latitude,
                      longitude: currentLocation.longitude),
                  _userGates,
                  distance: 0)
              .then((Map<String, Object> value) {
            _nearbyGate = value[Constants.GATE];
            notifyListeners();
          });
        });
```

Geolocator Library:

```
var geoLocator = Geolocator();
        var locationOptions = LocationOptions(
            accuracy: LocationAccuracy.bestForNavigation,);

        Position position = await Geolocator().getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.best);
        _approachingGate
            .getApproachingGate(position, _userGates,distance: 8)
            .then((Map<String, Object> value) {
          _nearbyGate = value[Constants.GATE];
          notifyListeners();

        });

        _positionStream = geoLocator
            .getPositionStream(locationOptions)
            .listen((Position position) {
              print("Coord: ${position.latitude} ${position.longitude}");
          _position = position;
          var x = 2.0;
          _approachingGate
              .getApproachingGate(position, _userGates,distance: x)
              .then((Map<String, Object> value) {
            _nearbyGate = value[Constants.GATE];

            notifyListeners();

          });
```

The `GeoLocator` library allows me to use `distanceFilter` to only update after moving a certain distance and for some reason it only works when it wants to.

Here is some of the outputs I just got now while I was busy typing this with my device dead still on the table.

```
I/flutter ( 7705): Coord: -26.1010019 28.0388391
I/flutter ( 7705): Coord: -26.101002 28.0388395
I/flutter ( 7705): Coord: -26.1010019 28.0388403
I/flutter ( 7705): Coord: -26.1010018 28.0388407
I/flutter ( 7705): Coord: -26.1010018 28.0388393
I/flutter ( 7705): Coord: -26.1010026 28.0388364
I/flutter ( 7705): Coord: -26.1010022 28.0388392
I/flutter ( 7705): Coord: -26.101002 28.0388393
I/flutter ( 7705): Coord: -26.1010021 28.0388405
I/flutter ( 7705): Coord: -26.1010024 28.03884
I/flutter ( 7705): Coord: -26.1010025 28.038839
I/flutter ( 7705): Coord: -26.1010022 28.0388383
I/flutter ( 7705): Coord: -26.1010423 28.0388409
I/flutter ( 7705): Coord: -26.1010033 28.0388375
```

Comment: This is due to GPS satellite movements skewing the data. Any app that does not have this problem is simply sorting and smoothing these results. For example, next time you go on a walk, use a route tracker, and stand still for about 5 minutes. You'll probably see a squiggly mess.

Comment: @spongyboss Did you find any way to resolve this location issue? Actually, I'm also facing the same issue.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is you are doing right. I mean, i worked a lot with Flutter Geolocator (and few time with Location) and i had the same issue. I studied deeply the APIs and the sources of Android. You can spot the explanation into the javadoc of the Android core library (FusedLocationProviderClient and Location).
For example at this link you can see that the "accuracy" of your GPS position returned by Android itself is 68% (more or less one sigma, with a Gaussian distribution). 
The javadoc warns you:

> *We define horizontal accuracy as the radius of 68% confidence. In other words, if you draw a circle centered at this location's latitude
>   and longitude, and with a radius equal to the accuracy, then **there
>   is a 68% probability that the true location is inside the circle**.*

So you have data produced everytime you start the service and no abstraction-library (as Geolocator or something like that) can do better than Android or solve the mistake.
IOs should be more accurate but i worked mostly with Android so i have few data about it.
Two links for the documentation:

Location:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location#getAccuracy()

FusedLocationProviderClient:

https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/FusedLocationProviderClient

I hope this help, 
regards.

Comment: Thanks but it's not complete ans. i follow this but still getting an issue of 0-100M accuracy. please tell me how to solve it. Thanyou